# Responding to mod requests

Tags: support, moderation, flagging

Is there any way for us to respond to a mod request / flag, besides revealing the user's email address and emailing directly?

For example, a recent mod flag suggested an answer wasn't an answer. It is, actually, an answer, just a bad one, which is what the voting is for. How can I relay this to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a moderator on a sister site ([TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)) and so far I know there is no method to contact a user directly for normal reasons. The moderator tools allow you contact users privately for serous reasons only (and this seems to now automatically suspend the user!). Using the moderator power to reveal the email address would be one way, but some users might not react well to this.

One way we do it sometimes on TeX.SX is that you add a comment to some post that user posted or commented (incl. `@username` of course) so he gets notified. Then afterwards the comment can be removed again. It's only semi-private ;-)

In theory you could also invite the user to a new dedicated chat-room you can create, but all conversation will be public and stay around forever, so this is hardly what you want.

Finally, you could go to the moderator chat channel and ask more experienced moderators how they handle this. You find a link to it on the [moderator dashboard page](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/admin/dashboard) in the right sidebar. Asking your question on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ might also be useful. It's not a homebrew.sx specific one after all.

Comment: Thanks @Martin!

Answer (score 1):

Now that [flag weight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight) is viewable and users can see their flag history, you can just dismiss the flag as `invalid`. The users flag weight will decrease and (if they are interested) they will see that no actions were taken in response to that flag.